# Pushing an empty promise and reassigning later

Tags: javascript, promise

```
var promises = []

array.forEach(element, i => {
    promises[i] = functionThatReturnsAPromise(element);
    if (somecondition) {
        promises[i] = new Promise(function(){}); // empty initial promise
        waitForSomeValue.then(function(result){
            promises[i] = functionThatReturnsAPromise(result); // reassign promise
        });   
    }
});

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Since there's a condition where I need to get the value first and then return a promise I'm creating an empty promise and reassigning it. However, this doesn't work, by that I mean Promise.all never returns a result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear how you `waitForSomeValue`. Whatever you're waiting for will happen after the loop finishes and promise all has been called.

Comment: it's it just `array.forEach(element, i => {
    promises[i] = someCondition
       ? waitForSomeValue.then(functionThatReturnsAPromise) : functionThatReturnsAPromise(element);
    }
});`

Comment: because `reassign promise` likely occurs AFTER `Promise.all(promises)`, you've already waited on a Promise that will never resolve, so it's too late

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `empty` promise never resolves. Reassigning a value in the array doesn't change anything after `Promise.all` was called. You should instead use chaining to assign a promise which does both, wait for the other value and then waits for your value.

```
array.forEach(element, i => {
    if(!somecondition)
        promises[i] = functionThatReturnsAPromise(element);
    else {
        promises[i] = waitForSomeValue.then(function(result){
            return functionThatReturnsAPromise(result);
        });   
    }
});
```

Or even simpler:

```
promises = element.map(el => {
    if(!somecondition)
        return functionThatReturnsAPromise(el);

    return waitForSomeValue.then(functionThatReturnsAPromise);   
});
```

Answer (score 3):

based on the code you provided

```
const promises = array.map(element => someCondition 
   ? waitForSomeValue.then(functionThatReturnsAPromise)
   : functionThatReturnsAPromise(element);
);
```